# On mouse over, show red bar before icon menu in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 6 icon, I want to display them as vertically, and before icon there is one red bar, will show the user mouse over effect, something like this :

[image]

how can I show this effect in CSS ?

what i try is this :

```
<div style="width: 20%; float: right";>
            <div>
                <div style="width: 20%; float: left; width: 26px; height: 26px">
                    <img  src="../../../Images/red_rectangle.png" /></div>
                <div style="width: 80%; float: right; width: 26px; height: 26px">
                    <img  src="../../../Images/Diploma_24.png" title="Education" /></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div style="width: 20%; float: left; width: 26px; height: 26px">
                    <img  src="../../../Images/red_rectangle.png" /></div>
                <div style="width: 80%; float: right; width: 26px; height: 26px">
                    <img  src="../../../Images/Medal_24.png" title="Membership" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**but by default i dont want to show red bar,
///*/// when mouse over : show red bar icon
when click on icon, :- i also want to remain show red bar , until user don't click on other icons**

Comment: We don't know what's the element type of these icons. And you didn't say what you already tried. Please post some HTML you've written.

Comment: you will probably want some jquery, and  your question is of horrible quality.

Comment: No need for jquery. It can be done with pure CSS

Comment: i think css will do this job, i saw example somewhere in internet , but not able to find

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/PcgaA/2/

### HTML

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/26/26" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/26/26" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/26/26" />
```

### CSS

```
img {
    border-left: 2px solid transparent;
    padding-left: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
}
img:hover {
    border-left-color: red;
}
```

Comment: It seems in the example like the element already have a border... Maybe using an outline will be more suitable

Comment: Updated to display horizontally. If you want vertical then add `display: block;`  to the `img` CSS.

Comment: your solution is good, i really dont need to use red image bar icon

Comment: You didn't understand what I was saying. Look at the picture in the OP. It looks like those items already have a black border so your solution won't work.

Comment: @Itay if that is the case then we can achieve this using a couple of other methods: altering the markup or adding `box-shadow` springs to mind

Comment: Or use an outline. Or :before pseudo class.

Comment: @itay, i just used paint to explain my word for question, i dont have black border icons

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `::after` to create a psuedo element.  The `div` elements will need replaced with `img` tags.

**CSS**

```
.selection{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin: 4px;
}

.selection:hover::before{
    content: ' ';
    width: 5px;
    background: red;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="selection"></div>
    <div class="selection"></div>
    <div class="selection"></div>
    <div class="selection"></div>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3RJJe/1/

Comment: but when select icon (image) i want to set red bar icon there, so user know that this icon is selected

Comment: If your looking to do this on click, I think you need to move to a JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this in ur CSS file

CSS styling:
    img {margin-left:5px;}
    img:hover {border-left:5px solid #f00}

Note: this is just generalized CSS, u will need to have specific CSS syntax.

```
<div>
<div>
    <img  src="../../../Images/red_rectangle.png" />
</div>
<div>
    <img  src="../../../Images/Diploma_24.png" title="Education" />
</div>
</div>
```

But this would be a better idea:

```
<ul class="my-menu">
<br>
    <li>
        <img  src="../../../Images/red_rectangle.png" />
    </li><br>
    <li>
        <img  src="../../../Images/Diploma_24.png" title="Education" />
    </li><br>
</ul>
```

CSS styling:

.my-menu li img {margin-left:5px; border-left:5px solid #fff}
.my-menu li img:hover {border-left:5px solid #f00}